# Trouble with the Samsung CUP sdk dialog example

Tags: java, android, android-studio, samsung-gear-fit

Using **Android Studio** to build a **Samsung Gear Fit** Dialog. I have an issue with this block of code. It seems to fail when I mListView uses the .setAdapter. There is a warning when I pass the demo_list into the mListView on initialization. So something may be wrong with this demo_list. I'm new to android so I'm not sure about a few things. The code base I am using has several layout files. I put the list view in the root_layout.xml the error referencing the demo_list goes away when I define the list in root_layout but it also goes away in other layout files.

So the problem is even when I define the demo_list the app crashes on initial load app crashes when using the setAdapter. Also when I put a break point and run it through debug there is circular logic in the findViewById method.

**Samsung Gear Fit (CUP SDK)**
http://forum.xda-developers.com/gear-fit/development/samsung-gear-fit-sdk-available-t2872803

My repo is 
https://github.com/jackygrahamez/MayDay

My code block in HomeActivity.java

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NAMES);

    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.demo_list);

    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // S Pen SDK Demo programs
            if (position == MAYDAY_CUP) {
                if (mHelloCupDialog == null) {
                    mHelloCupDialog = new GearFitDialog(getApplicationContext());
                } else {
                    mHelloCupDialog.finish();
                    mHelloCupDialog = null;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**Logcat**

```
02-07 15:11:39.059  11358-11358/com.mayday.md I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
02-07 15:11:39.079  11358-11358/com.mayday.md I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G900T_4.4.2_0034
02-07 15:11:39.079  11358-11358/com.mayday.md I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
02-07 15:11:39.079  11358-11358/com.mayday.md E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
02-07 15:11:39.079  11358-11358/com.mayday.md E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.mayday.md [ userId:0 | appId:10430 ]
02-07 15:11:39.079  11358-11358/com.mayday.md D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-07 15:11:39.319  11358-11358/com.mayday.md I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
02-07 15:11:39.359  11358-11358/com.mayday.md I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
02-07 15:11:39.399  11358-11358/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:720 height:1280 bitmap id is 270
02-07 15:11:39.429  11358-11358/com.mayday.md I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.360MB for 8294416-byte allocation
02-07 15:11:39.449  11358-11358/com.mayday.md D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-07 15:11:39.449  11358-11358/com.mayday.md W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41742da0)
02-07 15:11:39.449  11358-11358/com.mayday.md E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mayday.md, PID: 11358
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mayday.md/com.mayday.md.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mayday.md.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:62)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 15:11:44.829  11358-11358/com.mayday.md I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 11358 SIG: 9
02-07 15:12:29.939  12336-12336/com.mayday.md I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
02-07 15:12:29.949  12336-12336/com.mayday.md I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G900T_4.4.2_0034
02-07 15:12:29.949  12336-12336/com.mayday.md I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
02-07 15:12:29.959  12336-12336/com.mayday.md E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
02-07 15:12:29.959  12336-12336/com.mayday.md E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.mayday.md [ userId:0 | appId:10431 ]
02-07 15:12:29.959  12336-12336/com.mayday.md D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-07 15:12:30.259  12336-12336/com.mayday.md I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
02-07 15:12:30.309  12336-12336/com.mayday.md I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
02-07 15:12:30.339  12336-12336/com.mayday.md D/skia﹕ GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:720 height:1280 bitmap id is 270
02-07 15:12:30.349  12336-12336/com.mayday.md I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.354MB for 8294416-byte allocation
02-07 15:12:30.369  12336-12336/com.mayday.md D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-07 15:12:30.369  12336-12336/com.mayday.md W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41742da0)
02-07 15:12:30.379  12336-12336/com.mayday.md E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mayday.md, PID: 12336
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mayday.md/com.mayday.md.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mayday.md.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:62)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 15:12:33.289  12336-12336/com.mayday.md I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 12336 SIG: 9
```

Comment: you should attch your logcat for the crash part

Comment: By logic what do you mean?

Comment: Logcat: The Android logging system provides a mechanism for collecting and viewing system debug output. Logcat dumps a log of system messages, which include things such as stack traces when the emulator throws an error and messages that you have written from your application by using the Log class. You can run LogCat through ADB or from DDMS, which allows you to read the messages in real time.

Comment: I'm running via Android Studio on a Samsung Galaxy S5 device. I just attached the verbose Logcat with the package name filter com.mayday.md

Comment: @Xingchen also I got the repo now up to date with this code I'm struggling with https://github.com/jackygrahamez/MayDay

Comment: just wrote answer to your issue, suppose solve your problem.

Comment: @Xingchen you definitely deserve the Bounty. I will grant you that. But the goal is to get this CUP dialog to open and I have not accomplished that. I'll create a new post if I continue having trouble. THANKS!

Comment: Ok no problem, happy to help you solve the issue, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error logcat, and go through your HomeActivity 'onCreate()', I see that your codes:

```
setContentView(R.layout.welcome_screen);

and:

ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.demo_list);
```

however, there is no ListView 'R.id.demo_list' in your layout 'welcome_screen.xml', instead ListView 'R.id.demo_list' is defined in your layout 'fragment_type_simple.xml'.

So if layout 'fragment_type_simple.xml' is your HomeActivity UI, then you should replace:

```
setContentView(R.layout.welcome_screen);
with:
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_type_simple);
```

otherwise you should add ListView with id 'demo_list' in your layout 'welcome_screen.xml'.

Hope this is clear!